# How to Parse only 1 tag when there are mutiple of the same name using Xerces c++

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, xerces

I am trying to parse an xml file and I have located the correct title tag but there are multiple title tags and I need to parse just the first one.  Currently, my code outputs all title tags
For example:

```
<book>
   <title>
   <title>
   <title>
<book>
<movie>
   <title>
<movie>
```

I need just the first title in book.

My current code pulls all the title tags in book and outputs them.  Is there a way to stop after the first title?  Thanks.

```
void MySaxHandler::startElement(
const XMLCh* const uri,
const XMLCh* const localname,
const XMLCh* const qname,
const Attributes& attrs
) {
char* message = XMLString::transcode(localname);
if (strcmp(message, "book") == 0) {
    book = true;
}
else if (book && strcmp(message, "title") == 0) {
    title = true;
    titleBuffer = "";
}
else if (strcmp(message, "movie") == 0) {
    book = false;
}
else if (book && strcmp(message, "name") == 0) {
    title = false;
}
XMLString::release(&message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `title` flag a `size_t` and init it to `size_t(-1)`

Then change the `if (book && strcmp(message, "title") == 0)` into:

```
else if (book && strcmp(message, "title") == 0 ) {
    title++;
    if(0 == title) { // this is the one we want
      titleBuffer = "";
      // perhaps registering a callback with the parser - say, firstTitleFound
      // would allow you to do something like
      // firstTitleFound(titleBuffer);
      // and then capture the first titles of all the books in your document
    }
}
```

Maybe also reset the title to `size_t(-1)` whenever you encounter any element that can contain a title.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I have been playing with this code and it either prints the same thing or empty tags

Comment: @govCode Because the way you capture the title is a dummy one. If you don't know how to get you actual title content, raise another question. Otherwise, to test the code, add an `id` attribute to your title elements in your input doc and use the value of it (via `attrs` parameter) into the `titleBuffer`